# How to prevent the people in Zoom from hearing the sound (e.g. Youtube) on my PC without headphone?

Tags: audio, headphones, microphones

When I attend a Zoom meeting, I still want to watch Youtube. But I do not want the Zoom people to know that I am watching Youtube, i.e. I do not want them to hear any sound from my PC. Is that possible? I only want my voice to be heard.

I know wearing a headphone can achieve this, but I do not want to wear a headphone.

Someone told me "a modern array mic" may work, can I ask how to do it?

Comment: A directional microphone (like a "shotgun" mic) will be the best thing you can use to isolate only your voice and minimize other noise being picked up. This isn't a perfect solution though, if you are not talking then the YouTube noise might still be included in the background noise it picks up.

Comment: Here are some links to array mics - this is a pro system you can use for reference - https://www.shure.com/en-US/conferencing-meetings/solutions/microflex_advance whilst this is just what Amazon can find, a selection of cheaper consumer stuff in no particular order https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=conference+array+microphone&crid=38SIEBJKEJDUO&sprefix=conference+array+microphone%2Caps%2C74&ref=nb_sb_noss I honestly have no idea how you would find one suitable from that list, might have to look up reviews. I don't know these consumer systems at all so can't recommend any specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Mics aren't going to be perfectly isolated. If you dont want to use the best solution (headphones) then look at ear buds instead.  You can in ear ones that are not visible.

I wear on-top-of-ear hearing aids (coloured silver to match my hair), with transparent wires coming over the ear to go into little domes in the ear canal.  Not only are they not noticed by people at parties, they are not visible on Zoom.  People only notice them if they have one themselves or if you tell them about it.

Comment: As a headphone user (and earphone hater) I kinda like this option. The only problem with in-ear buds is that those tend to be pretty uncomfortable from my limited experience, but if that's no big deal for lanselibai then it's actually good

Comment: and also to make them invisible you need a lot of hair, which isn't a big deal for most people since it grows very close to the place where it needs to be to hide the earbuds